# What are the most desirable properties of a neural network?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I'm trying to compare a custom neural network architecture with other existing ones. I'm quite new to the CS field and I'm looking for desirable properties and/or applications of neural networks(especially recurrent architectures). Are there any?

Comment: Desirable for what purposes? This seems very opinion-based, to me.

Comment: @DavidRicherby that's the point: what, in your opinion, makes you choose an architecture? For example, transfer functions should have some desirable properties like non-linearity, differentiability, monotonicity... What about the neural networks instead?

Comment: 1. Subjective/opinion-based/open-ended questions typically aren't a good fit for this site's format.  We seek focused, answerable technical questions.  See http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask.  It might help if you edited your question to narrow it down (e.g., to a particular application domain, to list your goals for the neural network and how you will evaluate answers, etc.).

Comment: 2. What research have you done?  We expect you to do a significant amount of research before asking, and to show us in the question what you've come up with.  This helps us give you a better answer, and helps others who may come across your question.  See http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask.